# Computer won't boot to W8 metro interface

Tags: windows-8

Unlike most people, I want my PC to boot to the windows 8 metro interface, but it defaults to the old desktop.  How can I fix this?

Comment: did you install anything or do any registry hacks to make this happen?

Comment: That's not how the default is supposed to work (in fact Microsoft has made special efforts to not allow you to do this natively so I'm a little surprised).

You could try... install one of the start menu replacements that has an option to "boot to desktop".  Then, unselect that option and see if it updates the correct files/locations to reset the boot to metro (and then, uninstall it).  Little hacky, but it may work for you depending on what the root problem is.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that a desktop app installed a shortcut into either your startup folder or the Run registry key. The app launching at startup is what is causing the desktop to appear.

Run msconfig and check its Startup tab for any such apps.
If you're on a corporate network, a login script may cause such behavior.